# Add multiple items a SharePoint list

Tags: list, lookup-column

I am creating a suggestion list using SharePoint 2010 custom list. My issue is I want to give the login user the ability to add others users to the form. I am thinking of doing a parent Child relation, but OOB allows for it adding one item per one ID. I need to add multiple items for one ID, any help

Comment: did not get your requirement? You can not add multiple items for one system generated ID if that's what you want, can you please elaborate what you exactly want?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to add multiple persons to an item in a list, then the usual solution is to create a column of type Person and check Yes below "Allow multiple selections"

If the users aren't real users, then you might create on list with the candidates and in the other list add a lookup field and check "Allow multiple values"